# SQL select substring which is before the specified words

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I'm attempting to `SELECT` a substring from a larger string that should end before the words "STORE" or "PROTECT".

The problem is that there are a few scenarios in which the words "STORE" or "PROTECT" can appear before or after each other in a string, and we need to extract the substring that appears before either of those two words.

**Example Strings:**

1. "UNLABELLEDa ABCD EFGH IJKLM FOO BAR, STORE AT 15-30°C."  - *Here there is no "PROTECT" but "STORE" word exists, so we should get a substring before "STORE".*
2. "STORE UP TO 30°C (86°F). PROTECT FROM MOISTURE" - *In this string there is no string before first occurrence of a word "STORE" so substring will be **BLANK***
3. "MEPO BKHGT FOO BARFOO BAGK VIAL. PROTECT FROM LIGHT, STORE BETWEEN X°C TO Y°C." - *Query should return the substring before the word "PROTECT".*
4. "CARTON CONTAINING 1 X VIAL SB245063 100MG LYOPHILISED POWDER FOR RECONSTITUION.  STORE AT 2°C - 8°C.  PROTECT FROM LIGHT." - *In this string "STORE" word is exist before "PROTECT", so query should return a substring before the word "STORE".*
5. `NULL` - *when the string is null query should return a empty value instead of error.*

**SQL Query:**

```
DECLARE @TestVariable AS VARCHAR(MAX)='UNLAB ABCFG DRETFG FOO BARFOO 3990MG TABLETS, STORE AT 15-30°C.'

SELECT case when CHARINDEX('STORE', upper(@TestVariable)) > CHARINDEX('PROTECT', upper(@TestVariable))
then SUBSTRING(@TestVariable, 1, CHARINDEX('PROTECT', upper(@TestVariable))-1)
else SUBSTRING(@TestVariable, 1, CHARINDEX('STORE', upper(@TestVariable))-1)
end pack_description
```

If there are no words in a string from "PROTECT" or "STORE" and the string value is `NULL`, the query returns an error.

What changes should be made to this query based on the examples above to meet our requirements?

Comment: make a second case when for the STore and let else return 'no Value' or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is a poor platform to do text parsing because of it's very limited pattern matching capabilities. This would be better done in an application that supports *regular expressions* (regexes), because regexes can better check for context like word boundaries with expressions like `/\bSTORE\b/`.

However, if you need to do this in SQL server, you can add `LEN()` as a third position selector and `LEAST()` to chose the leftmost trim position. The `NULLIF()` function can also be used to map not-found 0 positions to null, so that they will be ignored. This also uses `LEFT()` instead of `SUBSTRING()`.

```
SELECT
    LEFT(D.String, LEAST(
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX('STORE', D.String), 0) - 1,
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX('PROTECT', D.String), 0) - 1,
        LEN(D.String)
        )) AS Result
FROM Data D
```

*Note that `LEAST()` is a new function only available in SQL Server 2022 and later. (Keep reading for alternatives that work in earlier versions.)*

Purely for aesthetic reasons, a `CROSS APPLY` can be used to separate the position calculation from the final select.

```
SELECT
     LEFT(D.String, A.TrimPos) AS Result
FROM DATA D. 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT LEAST(
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX('STORE', D.String), 0) - 1,
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX('PROTECT', D.String), 0) - 1,
        LEN(D.String)
        ) AS TrimPos
) A
```

For earlier SQL versions that don't have the `LEAST()` function, use:

```
...
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MIN(Pos) AS TrimPos
    FROM (
        VALUES
            (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('STORE', D.String), 0) - 1),
            (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('PROTECT', D.String), 0) - 1),
            (LEN(D.String))
    ) V(Pos)
) A
```

Keywords can also be placed in a table and use a subselect to search for any keyword. The `ISNULL()` function is used to inject `LEN()` as the default trim position.

```
SELECT
     LEFT(D.String, A.TrimPos) AS Result
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ISNULL(MIN(P.Pos), LEN(D.String)) AS TrimPos
    FROM (
        SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX(K.Keyword, D.String), 0) - 1 AS Pos
        FROM Keywords K
    ) P
) A
```

Finally, the current match logic can yield false hits if the text contains larger words like "protection" or "restorer" that partially match the keywords. This can be resolved by using `PATINDEX()` and prefixing the keywords with the not-a-letter pattern `[^A-Z]`.

```
SELECT
     LEFT(D.String, A.TrimPos) AS Result
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ISNULL(MIN(P2.AdjustedPos), LEN(D.String)) AS TrimPos
    FROM (
        SELECT NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]' + K.Keyword + '[^A-Z]%', ' ' + D.String + ' '), 0) - 2 AS Pos
        FROM Keywords K
    ) P
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT CASE WHEN P.Pos < 0 THEN 0 ELSE P.Pos END AS AdjustedPos
    ) P2
) A
```

Sample results

| Result | Tail |
| --- | --- |
| UNLABELLEDa ABCD EFGH IJKLM FOO BAR, | STORE AT 15-30°C. |
|  | STORE UP TO 30°C (86°F). PROTECT FROM MOISTURE |
| MEPO BKHGT FOO BARFOO BAGK VIAL. | PROTECT FROM LIGHT, STORE BETWEEN X°C TO Y°C. |
| CARTON CONTAINING 1 X VIAL SB245063 100MG LYOPHILISED POWDER FOR RECONSTITUION. | STORE AT 2°C - 8°C. PROTECT FROM LIGHT. |
| Just a description here |  |
| Finish restorer |  |
| Paint protection |  |
| Bananas. | Discard after 90 days. |
|  | null |
| null | null |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ePZb9R46) for a demo of each of the above.

Comment: I appreciate @T N's thorough explanation; your response has taught me new SQL concepts that I was unaware of.